# How do I mine with FPGAs?

Tags: mining-hardware, fpga

I'm not entirely sure how FPGA's work...

Do I simply buy a [ZTEX](http://www.ztex.de/usb-fpga-1/usb-fpga-1.15y.e.html) and it mines, or do I need to plug it into a computer via USB?

Can I chain them?

I'm so confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The very basic idea of an FPGA is that it can be loaded with a specific firmware (a layout of logical gates, in essence). That page contains the firmware you'd need to load onto a Xilinx FPGA (A Spartan 6) in order to use it as a mining device. ZTEX refers to a suite of the FPGA, and various IO controllers (USB, etc.).

Roughly speaking, the steps you'd need to follow would be:

1. Buy device
2. Plug in device to your computer
3. Load firmware onto device from your computer
4. Run a piece of software on your computer that interfaces with the firmware now loaded on the FPGA
5. Profit (in a couple years)

To answer your questions: yes, the device would need to be plugged in to a computer using the method in your link, and yes, you can "chain" them - i.e. have more than one plugged in. I've greatly oversimplified steps 3 & 4, by the way.

Comment: Oversimplified is such a great description - I'm using Modular Python Bitcoin Miner with a Mining_proxy software program.  IT works...but I'd like to discover how KNCminer converted their FPGAs to clock around a gigahash each and not ncecessarily 400 Mh

Comment: Which FPGA would you use for mining?

Comment: FPGA mining for bitcoin was never popular, and has not been economically viable since around the time this was written (2012). Hypothetically you'd want something recent (e.g. Stratix 10).