# How to get started with building an fpga mining device

Tags: fpga

I plan to make an fpga mining device for bitcoin mining just for the fun of it. I thought understanding bitcoin as  whole would be the first step to take. However I realize that understanding the whole verification and transaction process in bitcoin would take a lot of time. Time that I really dont have. So I just wanted to know what would be the most important things to know related to bitcoin before getting started as only solving the nonce would be the part that I write in verilog/vhdl. The remaining part related to understanding how bitcoin uses Script and processes transaction would be quite unnecessary to know since I am not going to use it for the project. Having said that knowing how the whole system works is important and I will do it but from the point of view of an fpga mining device I would like to know on what to really focus on?

Comment: How much verilog/VHDL do you know?

Comment: Not too much.I am getting started on that too but I have someone to guide me for the verilog part

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mine with FPGAs?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3539/how-do-i-mine-with-fpgas)

Answer (score 3):

See: [Open Source FPGA miner](https://github.com/progranism/Open-Source-FPGA-Bitcoin-Miner) and [additional info](http://hardcoreforensics.com/blog/2012/12/10/bitcoin-mining-publicly-available-vhdl-source-code-and-the-xilinx-xupv5/)

Comment: I had already looked at the open source fpga miner but I guess I forgot to mention it in the question. I will defintely look at hard core forensics. Do you think I should focus on any specific part of the bitcoin protocol